# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status - VSC

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-c++, c++17, mingw

Tengo un problema con visual studio code. Necestio hacer un programa en c++ y el IDE no me compila los programas que he hecho, en específico los que hago de forma orientado a objetos que tengo en archivos separados el main de las clases, por ejemplo tengo uno que hace arreglos pero lo tengo dividido en el archivo "main.cpp", el archivo de la clase donde hago los construcctores "arreglos.cpp" y su archivo header de la clase arreglos "arreglos.h".

[image: estructura de un proyecto]

Al compilarlo me da este error "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" pero si organizo el programa en solo el main, funciona.

Tengo instaladas las extensiones para c++ que pide IDE:

[image: extensiones de c++]

Instale el compilador que recomienda visual para windows (MinGW) y descargue los paquetes que se necesitan para usar el compilador:

[image: compilador de código para windows]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a saber por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code funciona bien cuando se trata de compilar un solo archivo.

Para trabajar cómodamente con un proyecto más grande la forma que encontré es mediante CMake.

---

Asegúrate de que tienes las extensiones instaladas (de CMake) y crea un archivo **CMakeLists.txt** en la carpeta abierta (Workspace) con Visual Studio Code.

Si no estás familiarizado con CMake, este permite configurar proyectos independientemente del sistema operativo y compilador. Puedes aprender a usarlo desde el [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html) que se encuentra en su documentación o buscar algún otro como [este](https://iamsorush.com/posts/cpp-cmake-essential/).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo básico:

```
# Versión mínima de CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Creas un proyecto e indicas su versión
project(Arreglos VERSION 1.0)

# Compila el proyecto con C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# El proyecto generará un ejecutable llamado "app".
# Le agregará la extensión necesaria. ".exe" en Windows.
add_executable(app)

# Agregas todos los .h y .cpp (o .c también)
# Las rutas son relativas al archivo CMakeLists.txt
target_sources(app PRIVATE
    arreglos.cpp
    arreglos.h
    main.cpp
)
```

Visual Studio Code detectará el archivo **CMakeLists.txt**, te solicitará elegir un compilador y te ofrecerá configurar Intellisense. [Más información](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/README.md).