# undefined reference VSCODE con múltiples fuentes

Tags: c++, vscode, libreria

SO: Windows

Hola gente.

Estuve buscando probar VSCode para seguir aprendiendo C++ y estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de ejecutar código que funciona perfecto en CodeBlocks

Asi llamo a la libreria header.h en el main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "lib\header.h"
```

Este seria el contenido de mi libreria header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

int FClase(int *vagon, int &asiento, int &cv1);
int FLectClass(int *vagon, int &asiento, int &cv1);
int SClase(int *vagon, int &asiento, int &cv2);
int SLectClass(int *vagon, int &asiento, int &cv2);
int ErasexClass(int *vagon, int asiento, int &cv1, int &cv2);

#endif
```

Aquí un ej de una de las funciones que se encuentre en otro archivo fuente

```
// Función que asigna un asiento en la Primera Clase y actualiza la cantidad de asientos ocupados
int FClase(int *vagon, int &asiento, int &cv1){
    for(asiento=0;asiento<5;asiento++)
    {
        if(vagon[asiento]==0)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Su ticket para el asiento numero #"<<asiento+1<<endl<<endl;
            vagon[asiento]=1;
            cv1++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El asunto es que cuando compilo mi programa, obtengo el siguiente error

```
undefined reference to `FClase(int*, int&, int&)'
```

Sinceramente no entiendo por que este error, solo he logrado solucionarlo llamando directamente a la fuente desde la librería, pero con CodeBlocks u otros IDE, no tengo que hacer eso. Donde podria estar el problema?

Comment: Mira si esta [respuesta que di](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/583383/169744) te ayuda.

Comment: Probablemente te falta añadir el archivo de código (¿`header.cpp`?) a los archivos a compilar, consulta si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593092/2742) te es de ayuda.

Comment: @Mateo Me sirvió tu respuesta, aunq con tantas vueltas, prefiero volver a codeblocks que me parece mas cómodo, lento, pero cómodo jaja

Comment: @Martin según veo puedes ahorrarte cmake haciéndolo como dice PaperBird. Fíjate si así te es más cómodo. Si, como puedes ver los IDE te lo ponen más fácil.